# Why do I read 20 microamperes instead of 5?

Tags: nodal-analysis

I am trying to do this experiment, but I can't read the current Ib. Note that the multimeter I use in this experiment is very sensitive. I don't know much about BJT transistors, so it might be an invalid transistor connection.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you know the "internal" impedance of your ammeter? In place of measuring "current" Ib, measure the voltage on Rb with an electronic voltmeter (of which you know the input impedance, do correction if needed against Rb).

Comment: >so it might be an invalid transistor connection. So, you are right ! +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For info about internal resistance, https://www.eeeguide.com/series-resistance-microammeter/

Just verify if it is easier ... measure directly ib, or v(Rb)/100k?

[image]

**If you reversed the BJT, then you are "right"!**

[image]

Comment: Our teacher said it must be 5 microamps and everyone except me obtained it.

Comment: Logical. See my answer ...

Comment: +1 Good catch @Antonio51

Comment: Thanks! I actually tried it flip vertically but I was trying to be quick so there should be other mistakes. Again thank you for your clear explanation.

Comment: It is the "only" simple means (from an external view) to distinguish emitter and collector, so you have learned something **important** ! ... It is the reason why on the multimeters, you can swap all "pins" to detect the "true" pinout of the BJT ... Thanks ... @devnull

Answer (score 4):

Just looking at the schematic, the collector current will be a bit less than 2mA before correcting for drop across Rb. If that transistor is a 2N2222A hFE should be between 50 and 300 so base current would be around 7 to 40uA, before correction.  So 20uA isn't really out of line.

Here's a simulation, result is 9uA Ib.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMA65K.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: But our lab assistant said that it must be 5 microamps, and my friends found correctly except me. I guess internal resistance of ammeter is negligible.